# Variance low and ceiling effect - split by median`?

Tags: correlation, variance, group-differences, heterogeneity, range

I heard that a sufficient amount of variance/heterogenity is needed in order to get reasonable results for a correlation test.
Why is that and what solutions exist when variance is too low?
Is splitting the obervations by a cut-off reasonable? F.e., the median?

(This question also relates to floor and ceiling effects)